# Mysql calculate total minutes

Tags: mysql, sql

How to total the minutes of the two dates? I mean I want to know the total minutes between from `2012-01-08 8:30` and `2012-01-09 14:11` using MySQL?

I have `initiate_date` and `finalize_date` columns in my table and I want to select them and display their total minutes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest [Timestamp difference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

For example

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, initiate_date, finalize_date)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 SELECT (TIME_TO_SEC(end_time) - TIME_TO_SEC(start_time))/60 AS `minutes`
```