# Find How many minutes a month has: MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Say I have a column

```
Date
23-03-2019
04-04-2019
```

I want to find hoe many minutes the whole month has in MySQL.

Expected output:

```
Date            MinsinMonth
23-03-2019       44640      
04-04-2019       43200
```

Comment: see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642155/mysql-calculate-total-minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT DAY(LAST_DAY(Date)) * 1440 AS MinsinMonth
```

[LAST_DAY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) returns the last day in the month a date is in

[DAY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day) Returns the day number associated to a date

1440 is the number of minutes per day (60 * 24)

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you just want to find the number of days in the month and then do some multiplication.  For this, use `last_day()`:

```
select day(last_day(date)) * 24 * 60 as minutes_in_month
```